# Cisco IP Phone Services - Dynamically Generate XML pages

Tags: asp.net, cisco, xml-generation

I am new to Cisco IP Phone Services (IPPS) and I am still trying to understand the concept behind it. 
I am a application developer, so I have much experience in web development either.

I have been looking at the Singlewire documentation from here:
http://www.singlewire.com/free-xml-apps.html

Here is my understanding so far:
The phone menus are in XML form, and when user select a menu, it is directed to another XML depending on the user input.

For example, 
The XML page for the StockQuote is:

```
<CiscoIPPhoneInput>
    <InputItem>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <DisplayName>Ticker Symbol</DisplayName>
        <InputFlags>A</InputFlags>
        <QueryStringParam>sym</QueryStringParam>
    </InputItem>
    <Prompt>Enter the ticker symbol</Prompt>
    <Title>Stock Quote</Title>
    <URL>http://www.singlewire.com/cgi-bin/stockquote.pl</URL>
</CiscoIPPhoneInput>
```

If the user input is CSCO, then it somehow generate the following page with XML in it: www.singlewire.com/cgi-bin/stockquote.pl?sym=csco

My questions:
1. After the user entered CSCO, how does the service know to go to the link www.singlewire.com/cgi-bin/stockquote.pl?sym=csco?
2. I am thinking stockquote.pl is a perl program that generates XML code base on the parameters "?sym=csco". I will be programming in .NET with Visual Studio. How can I create a stockquote.asp that dynamically create XML by looking at its parameters?

Thank you,
Lex

Comment: Check out this link for general info about Cisco development, XML expected formats, and to download the SDK:
https://developer.cisco.com/site/collaboration/endpoints/ip-phone-services/overview/ And this gives info about how to integrate ASP.NET for dynamic apps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15302/Cisco-IP-Phone-Services